# Dropdownlist index starts at -1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist and cant figure out the way index works. I have two items in the list, item1 is selected by default when the page is loaded. When the page is loaded, `item1` is selected and the index is -1. if I change item to `item2`, the index goes to 1. If I change back to `item1` it goes to 0.

Is the starting index allways -1? If so, is it possible to change that so that the starting index will be 0? What is the reason for this design?

Clairification:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 0;     //I try to set the index to 0
    myVariable = dropDownList1.SelectedIndex; //Debugger says SelectedIndex is -1
}
```

Comment: add this code `yourList.SelectedIndex = 0;` if you want to show the first Item on your page Load.

Comment: @TimSchmelter is it possible to change so that the index starts at 0 or 1? Or do I have to add 1 or 2 everywhere the index is read?

Comment: Does it have any items?!

Comment: @deostroll yep. 2 items

Comment: Are you data-binding to it? Or you are doing this in page markup?

Comment: @deostroll page markup

Comment: Weird. Just tried it in my VS. I observe that if you give an invalid index it will not update the SelectedIndex; it will retain its recently updated value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did a work-around now.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(dropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        myVariable = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        myVariable = dropDownList1.SelectedIndex;
    }
}
```

This works, but I still find it ugly. If anyone have a better solution please, let me know. =)

Answer (score -1):

Addition to my comment, -1 as index selected meaning and that is the default, no item will be shown on your dropdown when page on load. but you can add the `yourList.SelectedIndex = 0;`

Comment: yes it will show,but when the first load of page?,I think its not.

Comment: if there is no other item in the list - what else should be shown?

Comment: Nothing. As like nothing is selected.As i experience sir.

Comment: try this, Nothing ist no a part of the DataSource: ddlTest.DataSource = new List<string> { "item" }; ddlTest.DataBind(); when you start your website, "item" will be shown in your dropdown